# Custom script in install4j build process

Tags: install4j

We are working with Dev- and Production variables as compiler variables in our install4j project. Is it possible to add sort of a custom script for the build process, that for example checks the value of a compiler variable?

Or is there any other idea how we can be sure, that there is no compiler variable on "DEV" instead of "PRODUCTION"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 8.0 there is no compiler API of any kind, so it is not possible to have any active component at built time. This is planned for a future version of install4j.